# Ubuntu 12.04 Nvida 550ti drivers

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics, display

I can't seem to locate any working drivers for the 550ti. I have downloaded the file from nvidias site and run it, but it just doesn't seem to help. I am still unable to increase the resolution, however after running this I am able to boot with the graphics card, without the driver from nvidia it just displays a purple screen when trying to boot. Does anyone know how I can get this card working properly?

UPDATE: 
Ok, so I have managed to install with nomodeset with the graphics card installed, however I am now having an issue with increasing the resolution, please see the below information:
pastebin.com/LrH2jm6c
pastebin.com/tscCiybw

Does anyone have any ideas why my resolution is restricted?

Comment: Did you have any problems with the included proprietary driver (nvidia-current, also available from System Settings -> Available Drivers)?  I have that a 550ti and it works absolutely fine.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately so. I am unable to install Ubuntu while using the 560ti. For some reason I get get a black screen with a cursor. I then removed the card and installed from the on board graphics, but when trying to boot with the 560ti it just hangs on a purpleish screen. I am at a total loss :( I've reinstalled again and even using the drivers on the Nvidia isn't working any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our small conversation in the comments it appears that your problem is you haven't even been able to try installing the included proprietary driver yet, because you can't even run the installer (or, if you do run the installer without the graphics card present, you then cannot boot once you replace the graphics card).

Having virtually the same card as you, I found that for whatever reason, the nouveau drivers supplied with Ubuntu 12.04 just don't seem to work with this card - and don't allow it to boot into X properly (even for the graphical installer).  *Interestingly, the nouveau drivers included with Ubuntu 11.10 did work, so not sure what happened*.

For the installer CD, there is an easy workaround - at the initial boot screen when the keyboard icon appears, press any key to get a menu, and find the menu option that allows you to boot with the **nomodeset** option.  Without modesetting enabled, nouveau won't load (which means you'll get ugly, slow graphics, but this is only temporary!).

Since you have already managed to install Ubuntu by running the installer without the graphics card present, you don't need this step.

The next step is that you now need to install the proprietary driver on Ubuntu without being able to boot into X.  You could try installing the package `nvidia-current`.  This can be done using the command line.  There will be an option in your boot loader to boot to command line - if your boot loader doesn't come up then holding SHIFT while booting should do it.

I can't fully recall, but you may also need to install `nvidia-xconfig` and run that, to set up your video driver for X after you've installed it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have now successfully installed directly off the 560ti and made sure I have the latest drivers, however I am still unable to change the resolution. I can't help but to think I am missing something. Installed with nomodeset and booted after install successfully.

Comment: Does running nvidia-settings tell you anything useful or allow you to make any adjustments?  What about System Settings -> Details -> Graphics?  What I'm getting at is do you know which driver you're actually running now?

Comment: Ahhh this is definitely a step I missed. I didn't realise that this was on here to change the resolution. 

OK, so I can now increase my resolution by one step (up to 1360x768) but I should definitely be able to go higher, both graphics card and monitor support this. Any ideas how I can get a higher resolution? Thank you so much for all your help so far :)

Comment: It might be helpful to know what drivers your system loaded at startup, try `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep drivers`, and what monitor and resolutions are detected, for that try `xrandr` (both should be run from a terminal window inside your graphical desktop).

Comment: Thank you for your continued help neon_overload, it is much appriciated. I have uploaded the outputs to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/tscCiybw

Comment: I have tried to addmode via xrandr, however I get the following error:
required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(1440, 900), minimum=(320, 240), maximum=(1152, 864)

I am assuming that Ubuntu isn't detecting my monitor, but I've tried 2 monitors with the same issue.

Comment: I have also uploaded my xorg.conf contents to: http://pastebin.com/LrH2jm6c  if this is of any help

Comment: Your Xorg log indicates that nouveau is being loaded, but not the nvidia driver.  The xrandr output indicates it's not detecting your monitor resolution properly (either that, or it's detecting a 1024x768 monitor).  This *may or may not* resolve itself it you get the nvidia driver to load instead.  Your xorg.conf is what you would expect from nvidia-settings.  I'm afraid I'm not sure why that's not loading the nvidia driver, but if you add all those pastebins to your original question, others may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have finally resolved this (at last) The issue seems to have been with the fact I was using a DVI adapter.. I'm assuming Ubuntu wasn't able to read this through the adapter.

Thanks you to neon_overload for all the assistance. I can now move on with trying to get to grips with Ubuntu.